# json object to array not referencing values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm doing something stupid and can't figure it out.

I'm pulling setting details stored in a mysql database as a json object and then converting them to an array.

`$settings = (array)json_decode($user['settings']);`

I can `print_r()` this to the following:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
```

Good so far.

If I try to update one of the settings, so for example changing 1 to equal 0, I get this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [1] => 0
)
```

I'm doing this simply with this:

`$settings[1] = 0;`

Ultimately I'm trying to unset the value if it's a 0 and then update the database. Instead of updating the value, it's creating a new entry and using `unset` doesn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong??

full code snippet for reference:

```
$settings = (array)json_decode($user['settings']);
print_r($settings);

if(isset($form['usr'][$user['id_user']])){
    $settings[1] = 1;
}else{
    $settings[1] = 0;
    unset($settings[1]);
}

print_r($settings);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [1] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can you add secent param true to function json_decode like that :

```
$settings = json_decode($user['settings'], true);
```

I think this fix problem

Answer (score 0):

For one, I see a syntax error in your code. Is it a typing error or it is part of the actual code you did run? This line to unset ->

```
unset($settings[1];)
```

The statement termination ";" should be outside as this

```
unset($settings[1]);
```

Here is what I have tried.
Assuming the $user['settings'] is formed this way

```
$user['settings'] = array('2' => 1, '1' => 1);
```

And was turned to json object in this manner

```
json_encode($user['settings']);
```

Then the following code should work

```
$settings = (array)json_decode($user['settings']);
print_r($settings);

if(... true)
{
   $settings[1] = 1;
}
else
{
    $settings[1] = 0;
    unset($settings[1]);
}

print_r($settings);
```

Should output

```
Array
(
   [2] => 1
   [1] => 0
)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo; I typed too fast and have amended.

Comment: yep. working with the answer from user3146300 - it was the option that needed to be set to force it to convert to an associative array in the `json_decode`

Comment: okay good. i tested both the casting and setting the second param to true and both worked fine with my code. anyway good if u've answer.